# Unable to do a perishable-network demo setup

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Trying to setup demo environment by deploying 'Perishable-Network' under Hyperledger playground.

Encountering following error when we select 'setupdemo' after clicking on   'Submit Transaction' in 'Test' mode.

```
t: Instance org.acme.shipping.perishable.TemperatureReading#bdab2372-b400-41c8-a0fa-201d670864bf missing required field centigrade
```